# Is there a Java Map implementation that enforces final keys?

Tags: java, dictionary

I need a `Map`, that once a key gets a value, any additional attempt of putting a value on the same key will throw an exception.

For example:

```
map.put("John", 3); //OK
map.put("John", 7); // throws some exception
map.put("John", 11); // throws some exception
```

Of course I can implement this on my own (e.g. by extending `HashMap`, or surrounding every call to `put` with `if map.contains(key)`), but I prefer using something ready-made that keeps my code clean.

Does anybody know of such implementation?

Comment: Why `extends`? Just use composition

Comment: Indeed wrap a hashmap and check if the key exists before putting a new value

Comment: Guava's [`ForwardingMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html) does most of the work if you want to use composition.

Comment: it is just a checking before put, just DIY. but keep in mind that making the impl. thread safe, since the hashmap's put() is not synchronized

Comment: Don't do it by extending HashMap. Do it by wrapping another map (using, for example, http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html)

Comment: @user2357112 Why is composition better here than extending? If I extend I don't have to delegate all the methods (which may be more error-prone).

Comment: @OferBr: 1. No [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) 2. If the base class changes (say, a method is added), your subclass may break (and you could not remove `extends HaspMap` without breaking backwards compatibility, because that is part of the interface). The real problem here is that the class is non-`final` by chance, not by design. See [fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). See Joshua Bloch, Effective Java, Theme 16 for more information (BTW I strongly recommend that book to any OOP programmer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no such implementation in the JDK. Your best bet here is to use composition:

```
public final class CustomMap<K, V>
    implements Map<K, V>
{
    private final Map<K, V> delegate;

    public CustomMap(final Map<K, V> delegate)
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(final K key, final V value)
    {
        // Can't use the return value of delegate.put(), since some implementations
        // allow null values; so checking delegate.put() == null doesn't work
        if (delegate.containsKey(key))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate key: " + key);
        return delegate.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(@Nonnull final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)
    {
        for (final Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry: m.entrySet())
            put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    // delegate all other methods
}
```

Otherwise, as others suggested, if you use Guava, use ForwardingMap; this is essentially a generalized version of the above code.

In fact, *do* use Guava.

---

other note: you can't just `// throws some exception` here; `Map`'s `.put()` doesn't declare to throw any exception, so your only option is to throw an unchecked exception here.

Comment: This works, however it does violate the contract of the Map interface and should therefore not implement the Map interface.

Comment: Well, what other choice do you have?

Comment: If you only used it inside of your application you should create your own interface that reflects the changed contract. If you need it to pass to other code (library, etc) you should probably not do it or think very, very careful about the consequences.

Comment: That's a given, of course; but creating your own interface? Disagree. Just document what you do and that's all. Just as `ForwardingMap` from Guava makes no guarantee as to implementations.

Comment: And for the love of god, put something in that Exception to tell the next guy up the try-catch chain exactly what value was duplicate.  :-)

Comment: I don't understand the final comment. [Map's `put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true#put%28K,%20V%29) does declare 4 exceptions, among them there is IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: +1, but note that doing a `containsKey()` and then a `put()` leaves you vulnerable to a data race if you have multiple threads writing to the map simultaneously. Safest would be to take a separate lock around those two operations.

Comment: @DanielPryden I never said the code was thread safe ;) Map is not thread safe for that matter

Comment: @ignis Map's .put() prototype does not `throws` anything; it is no coincidence that possible exceptions are only _documented_ and not declared

Comment: No, it could equivalently `throws` IAE and other unchecked exceptions (and errors, for that matter), but that was not my point anyway (and is irrelevant from the point of view of Java/javac/JVM). Throwing IAE in this case is just adhering to the put() contract with "the" pertinent exception - I don't see it as a "last resort", as the "your only option" wording implies that other options would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

[`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) class in Google Java libraries (Guava) is the solution you are looking for. You want final keys which implies that the values in your map will also be final-alike.
And you can build your map like this:

```
ImmutableMap<String,Integer> myMap = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
    .put("john", 3) 
    .put("rogerio", 5)
    .put("alfonso", 45)
    .put("leonidas", 577)
    .build();
```

Comment: 1. `ImmutableMap` is not in the JDK but in Guava (I wish it were in the JDK though); 2. it is, well, immutable; what is more it does not accept null keys nor values.

Comment: And, it's put() method is deprecated.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to indicate that the map's life can be divided into "build" and "use" phases. If it can't, `ImmutableMap` isn't an appropriate solution.

Comment: @user2357112 - Exactly. The question doesn't specify that the user shouldn't be allowed to add new key value pairs.

Comment: @TheLostMind That is true, this solution is partially applicable.

Comment: @user2357112 You're absolutely right, this won't do for my case. Adding keys happens in various times, there is no defined "build" stage.